# Placing the same link twice

Tags: html, css, facebook, google-plus

I am using Facebook and Google+ comment widgets on a page. Because the page is responsive, when the page shrinks bellow 767px then the tab title will disappear and the icons will remain. This causes me to place the link on the icon instead of the tab. I cannot figure out how to get the title to disappear and have the link remain on the tab. Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#tabs-1"><img src="/images/icon-facebook.png" alt="Facebook Icon" /><p class="tabTitle">Comment on <strong class="fbBlue">Facebook</strong></p></a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-2"><img src="/images/icon-plus.png" alt="Google+ Icon" /><p class="tabTitle">Comment on <strong class="googleRed">Google+</strong></p></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#tabs li{
    font-size: .875em;
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
.tabTitle{
        display: none;
    }

    #tabs-1{
        width: 80%;
    }

    #tabs-2{
        width: 80%;
}

.g-comments{
    width: 90%;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need another newline after "HTML:" in your question to properly format your posted HTML code.

Comment: thanks...I hadn't used this page in a little while.

Comment: I don't understand your question can yor reproduce it on a jsfiddle example it works fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/yLZp2/

Answer (score 0):

Used etiquete correct meta viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Tha'ts code correct is:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    ul li p {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Aua95/